# Power and friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction, power

An object moves with a constant velocity of 10m/s on a rough surface with frictional force of 50N. What is the power of the object? And why do we use force of friction instead of the force provided by the object to calculate power?

Answer (score 1):

If the object is moving at constant velocity the net force on the object is zero.
So the externally applied force on the object must be equal in magnitude but opposite in direction to the frictional force.  50 N in the opposite direction to the frictional force.
It is not the power of the object which you are finding, it is the power delivered to the object to work against the frictional force.